# Groovy grep a word

Tags: groovy, grep

I wanted to grep for java process and then find the max heap memory used.
I tried this

```
def ex =['sh','-c','ps -aef | grep Xmx']
String str =  ex.execute().text
```

while `str` has something like *java -Xmx1024M /kv/classes/bebo/ -Xms512M*
How do I extract the value *1024M*? I was planning to user java regex but thought someone might know a cool way in groovy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a groovy version that doesn't need the grep (or the sed :) :

```
("ps -aef".execute().text =~ /.*-Xmx([0-9]+M).*/).each { full, match -> println match }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
String ResultString = null;
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("-Xmx(\\d+M)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(str);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the value after Xmx, you could have that returned to you from the ex:

```
def ex =['sh','-c',"ps -aef | grep Xmx | sed -e 's/^.*Xmx\([0-9]*[mM]*\) *$/\1/'"]; 
String str = ex.execute().text;
```

The sed command will transform the output of ps into just the bit that comes out of ps before returning.